# How to remove buttons when MyLocationEnabled is on in google_maps_flutter

Tags: flutter

Whenever MyLocationEnabled is true, there are buttons that show up to take the camera to the current location. On iOS I covered it up using my own FloatingActionButton, but on Android it's in the top left so I can't cover it up. Is there any way to remove these buttons while keeping the current location shown on the map?